# Ресурсы в Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, android-resources, monogame

Первый раз пишу под `android` и мне надо добавить небольшую базу данный в формате `xml`, как я понял на `android` все такие фокусы прокатывают через папку `Resources`, я создал там подкаталог `Xml`, закинул в него мой файл, и теперь появилась проблема: я не знаю что делать с переменной типа `XmlDocument`, т.е. я объявил то ее ну не знаю как в нее запихнуть мой документ. Подскажите как или получить путь файла, чтоб еще все в `apk` нормально работало или ссылку на сам файл типа `XmlDocument`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. поместите свой filename.xml в **Resources/Raw** проекта
2. в Properties xml-файла в проекте **Build Action** -> **AndroidResource**
3. компилируете. После этого ресурс будет доступен через `Resource.Raw.filename`
4. открывать ресурс `Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Raw.filename)`. Эта штука возвращает `Stream`
5. затем получаете `XmlReader` через `XmlReader.Create`(сюда передаёте Stream)

Comment: но эту базу вы не сможете изменять. если потом это потребуется, её нужно будет сохранять куда-нибудь.